# ScrollIntoView() can find the html element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, js-scrollintoview, create-ref

**I'm trying to create a scroll to element but I'm getting this error**

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null".
By console logging mapRef I can see that I'm getting the correct div.
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2qrO.png)

```
export class FinderComponent extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mapRef = React.createRef();
  }

  renderMap() {
    return <div block="StoreFinder" ref={this.mapRef}></div>;
  }

  renderStoreCard(store) {
    this.mapRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    //console.log(this.mapRef.current);
    return (
      <div
        block="StoreFinder"
        elem="Store"
        key={store_name.replace(/\s/g, "")}
        mods={{ isActive: store_name === selectedStoreName }}
      >
        {this.renderStoreCardContent(store)}
        <button
          block="Button"
          mods={{ likeLink: true }}
          onClick={() => changeStore(store)}
        >
          {__("Show on the map")}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.mapRef.current` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this functional component that has a working example with ScrollIntoView(). If I understood you right, you want to add the scrollIntoView()-function to an element. This is how you do it with functional components:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export const TestComponent = () => {
  const inputEl = useRef(null) //"inputEl" is the element that you add the scroll function to

  useEffect(() => {
    inputEl.current.scrollIntoView() //use this if you want the scroll to happen when loading the page
  }, [inputEl])

  const onButtonClick = () => {
    inputEl.current.scrollIntoView() //use this if you want the scroll to happen on click instead.
  }
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  )
}
```